# I want to set (updatable=false) in my neo4j property

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am working with spring-data-neo4j and i finally made auditing in my project.

This is my config for audit

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jAuditing
class AuditingConfig {

    @Bean
    fun auditorProvider(): AuditorAware<Long> = SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl()
}

class SpringSecurityAuditAwareImpl : AuditorAware<Long> {

    override fun getCurrentAuditor(): Optional<Long> {
        val authentication: Authentication? = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication

        if(authentication?.isAuthenticated != true ||
                authentication is AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
            return Optional.empty()

        val userPrincipal = authentication.principal as UserPrincipal

        return Optional.ofNullable(userPrincipal.id)
    }
}
```

and this is my audit class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value = ["createdAt", "updatedAt"],
        allowGetters = true
)
abstract class DateAudit : Serializable {

    @CreatedDate
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null

    @LastModifiedDate
    val updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null
}
```

It work perfectly when entity make first.
But when update entity, the "createdAt" property is null.

I know the @CreatedDate is just work when entity created.
After create, it set null .
In JPA, this problem can be avoided by @Column(updatable = false).

So, I want to know spring-data-neo4j has annotation like @Column(updatable = false)
or solution avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should init the "createdAt" property

Comment: When I update entity, I found entity by repository. So, the createdAt property has value. but when i save(update) entity by neo4jrepository, the value is changed to null.